# Refactor long try-except chain

Tags: python, django, exception, try-catch

I have a feeling that this sequence might be written shorter:

```
dim = Dimension.objects.get(pk=rows['pk'])
try:
    dim.name = rows['name']
except KeyError:
    pass
try:
    dim.external_flg = rows['external_flg']
except:
    pass
try:
    dim.ext_owner = rows['ext_owner']
except KeyError:
    pass
try:
    dim.ext_table_name = rows['ext_table_name']
except KeyError:
    pass
try:
    dim.ext_start_date_column_name = rows['ext_start_date_column_name']
except KeyError:
    pass
try:
    dim.ext_end_date_column_name = rows['ext_end_date_column_name']
except KeyError:
    pass
```

I've never had any experience in Python code optimization and working with exceptions but I'd be glad to have an alternative examples how it could be shortened.

Thank you!

Comment: Is `rows` your dictionary object?

Comment: Maybe asking the question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate.

Comment: It's type(rows).__name__ can be 'dict' or 'list'.

Comment: bvidal, does StackExchange have a function of moving questions to a more appropriate section?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `dict.get()` method:

```
dim.name = rows.get('name', dim.name)
```

Or, for more DRY solution, put all assignments into the loop:

```
for field_name in ('name', 'external_flg', 'ext_owner', 'ext_table_name',
                   'ext_start_date_column_name', 'ext_end_date_column_name'):
    if field_name in rows:
        setattr(dim, field_name, rows[field_name])
```

To handle the `list` data you can make the similar loop:

```
for i, field_name in enumerate(('name', 'external_flg', 'ext_owner',
                                'ext_table_name', 'ext_start_date_column_name',
                                'ext_end_date_column_name')):
    if i < len[rows]:
        setattr(dim, field_name, rows[i])
```

Comment: In my case, it can be a list also.

Comment: You can do the same trick with the list.  See the updated answer,

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work — this answer includes try/catch block to catch KeyError :-)

```
attributes = ['name', 'external_flg', 'ext_owner', 'ext_table_name',
               'ext_start_date_column_name', 'ext_end_date_column_name']

dim = Dimension.objects.get(pk=rows['pk'])

for attr in attributes:
    try:
        setattr(dim, attr, rows[attr])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```